# Formatting Dates Stored as Strings

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am working with a string column that holds date values (I didn't design it, but I do have to work with it).  There are about 2500 records.

Most of the date values are entered in MM/DD/YYYY format (with preceding '0's), but there are some rogue records that are in MM/DD/YY format, or others that don't have preceding '0's.

Example of source data:

```
05/20/2012
05/20/2012
5/29/2011
5/6/2015
5/1/10
```

I need to return a distinct list of values, all formatted the same way (MM/DD/YYYY), in order.

```
05/01/2010
05/29/2011
05/20/2012
05/06/2015
```

Given the lack of consistency in how these values were entered, I'm not sure how to accomplish the goal?

Comment: If you are going to standardize the dates, I would recommend the ISO standard format of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: In this case `5/1/10` no one can say which value is a year, a month or a day. I guess that there also could be dates like `10/11/12` in this table - it's guessing game, you need some additional criteria to decide which format has to be used in this case. Also a date like `10/12/2015` - please tell mi which value is a month and which one is a day ?

Comment: @algor - I'm on Oracle 11g

Comment: @kordirko - I feel comfortable assuming a value such as 5/1/10 is intended to mean May 1, 2010. This is a highly localized database, and I see my colleagues use that format often.

Comment: Well, if there are only 2 possible formats, then use REGEXP to check a format of the field, and use an appropriate format in to_date function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dates in the column are in only 2 possible formats:
x/xx/xx -> mm/dd/yy
xx/xx/xxxx -> mm/dd/yyyy
then use simple `to_date( column_name, 'mm/dd/yy' )` to convert strings to dates,
and then `to_char( value, 'mm/dd/yyyy' )` to convert dates back to required format. 
Simple:

```
to_char( to_date( column_name, 'mm/dd/yy' ), 'mm/dd/yyyy' )
```

You can use only one conversion format `mm/dd/yy` in to_date function, because of conversion rules used by Oracle and descibed here (under topic "String-to-Date Conversion Rules" ):
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

In short - if a format model `mm/dd/yy` doesn't match to string like `10/12/2014`, then Oracle automatically tries alternative format model: `mm/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not given what DB is used in this particular case. Let's assume that this is Oracle DB and all dates start with Month, and desired result is string, and 5/1/10 is not 1st of May 1910. You can do this:

```
select to_char(to_date('5/1/10', 'MM/DD/YY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;
select to_char(to_date('05/20/2012', 'MM/DD/YY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;
select to_char(to_date('5/29/2011', 'MM/DD/YY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;
select to_char(to_date('5/6/2015', 'MM/DD/YY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;
```

you'll get

```
05/01/2010
05/20/2012
05/29/2011    
05/06/2015
```